# Mocking Microsoft Graph SDK V5

Tags: sdk, moq, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using the current version of the Microsoft graph sdk (5.2) and i have registered the GraphServiceClient in my dependency injection.

This is consumer in another service and injected in via the constructor.
When trying to unit test this class I need to inject a mocked GraphServiceClient in but I can't seem to mock it. I get errors stating a constructor can't found which matches.

I have had very little luck finding documentation on this or any example for the recent version.

I have tried the following example:

```
// Arrange
var mockAuthProvider = new Mock<IAuthenticationProvider>();
var mockHttpProvider = new Mock<IHttpProvider>();
var mockGraphClient = new Mock<GraphServiceClient>(mockAuthProvider.Object, mockHttpProvider.Object);
```

But the IHttpProvider seems to be defunct in this version and I can't find it in the nuget package.If I try and do it without the IHttpProvide and just use the mock auth provider i get the constructor error:

```
    var mockAuthProvider = new Mock<IAuthenticationProvider>();
            var mockGraphClient = new Mock<GraphServiceClient>(mockAuthProvider.Object);
```

> System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class:
> Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient. Could not find a constructor that
> would match given arguments:
> Castle.Proxies.IAuthenticationProviderProxy  (Parameter
> 'constructorArguments')